# gorm filter on hasMany column

Tags: grails, subquery, grails-orm

I have 2 domainClasses as below :

```
class Customer {
   def name   
   static hasMany = [accounts:Account]
}

class Account {
   def accountNo
   def type
}
```

Here Account's type can be 'Saving','Current','FD'

I want to write a criteria to search all those customers who have account types 'Saving','Current'.

What should be the criteria, I tried using below :

```
def customers = Customer.createCriteria().list {
    accounts {
         and {
            eq('type','Saving')
            eq('type','Current')
        }
    }
}
```

But when it executes it create inner join which is giving 0 result.

Comment: What happens if you use OR instead of AND ?

Comment: As I want to get all customers who have both types of accounts

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `or` instead of `and` as suggested by Y. Tarion or use `in`:

```
def types = ["Savings", "Current"]
def customers = Customer.createCriteria().list {
    accounts {
        "in" "type", types
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this query return the customers who have either type "Savings" or "Current" but actually I want the customers who have atleast both types of accounts they may have more than these 2 types of accounts as well like "Savings","Current" or "Savings","Current","FD" etc.

Comment: OK now I got you.
Actually it is a bit complicated and I am not sure if you can do this with criteria. The SQL would look like:
select * from customer where id in (select customer_accounts_id from customer_account where account_id=1) and id in (select customer_accounts_id from customer_account where account_id=2)
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation

Comment: I tried by following way but its not generating appropriate out put :

def results = Customer.withCriteria {
         accounts.each {
           'in' "id" , new DetachedCriteria(Account).build {
            projections {
               property('customer.id')
             }
            eq('type',it)
           }
          }